# No module named 'data'

Tags: python-import, importerror

I get the error No module named 'data' whenever I try to execute the line below

```
from data import batch_gen, encode
```

Can anyone help me fix this? I tried looking into other online resources but could not fix this problem.

Comment: Did you properly install it with `pip`?

Comment: what error you are getting.

Comment: Yes I installed properly using pip. I am getting the error "No module named 'data'"

Answer (score 1):

try the following and then do your import:

```
pip install data
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
from data import batch_gen, encode
```

lets you import only parts of modules and gives you the possibility to reference them directly without writing data.encode

So to get this running you need a module called data in a file, either a file in the same location as your python file or in the installation folder where the other std python files life. otherwise you would always get an error. more information is easily found here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-modules-in-python-3#using-from-%E2%80%A6-import